# What is the Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render environment variable for?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

After running:

```
env  ; #from with in terminal
```

I see the following output:

```
...
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-pc2V6P/Render
...
```

What is this environment variable used for? Not really finding anything about what its for and why it is set by default.

Comment: Why are you asking?

Comment: Because I have read this http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/cli-crash-coursech22.html

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve, or are you just curious?

Comment: Yes what thats variable is for, I think the answer solves that...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PubSub is the backend for how Safari and Mail handle RSS feeds.  There are command line utilities too. From the [pubsub man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pubsub.1.html):

> pubsub -- Utility for managing RSS/Atom subscriptions via the PubSub framework

This variable is just part of that process.

The ability to read RSS feeds in Safari is going away in Mountain Lion, but I don't know if the entire RSS infrastructure is going away too.

Comment: For information, it's still here on 10.11.5.

Comment: For information, it's still here on 10.13.6

Comment: Command still present on 10.14.5